# How do i reduce cufon flickering on render?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, cufon, font-replacement

I'm working on a project using Cufon font replacement, and we're having a rather frustrating issue with a flicker when the content is rendered in the browse. You can see it as your browser around the site [here](http://urbangolf.mammalworld.com/).

The effect is worst in internet explorer but also noticeable in all other browsers, any way to reduce this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://urbangolf.mammalworld.com/   This link not worked///

Comment: the link is now http://www.urbangolf.co.uk/ and the project is complete

Comment: site looking wonderful nanba.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that flicker is effected by the amount of content loading on the page and the speed they all come in.  The quicker response time from the server and the less items loaded will lower the flicker time.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the text while cufon loads, then display the text once it's active.

**See** https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/styling#jump-special-cases